# Unable to use all the memory of Allview A5 Smiley

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I bought some days ago an Allview A5 Smiley. I installed some applications and made some photos. Now, I saw that I can't install files bigger than approximately 200 MB because it is only free space on phone. This is strange, because the phone has 4 GB of storage. I looked in Settings and I saw that I still have about 1.5 GB free, but I can't use for applications. Why this happens and how I can fix it?

Some screens shots:

<sub>(Click image to enlarge)</sub>

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**Thanks!**

Comment: Try the [insufficient-memory tag wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) , it may be helpful

Comment: I added a as of diskinfo.

Comment: Sorry, Mihail: that's an all-present issue. Aleksandar pointet to the correct place for how to deal with it. User data (and apps you install) are stored in a separate partition, which is almost full on your device – so no matter how much space you've got elsewhere, apps still want to go there and can't.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on an Allview P5 Life and I solved it by simply upgrading to Android 5.0 Lollipop.
I used to have an A5 Smiley before this one as well, and I had the same problem... what I did to make it better was to root the phone and remove the bloatware saving a pretty substantial amount of space. This is however not really recommended and you should do it at you'r own risk.
You *could* also try to install another ROM. There's no official upgrade but you can probably find an unofficial compatible ROM on the internet. This is a very risky endeavour and I really don't recommend it... even I didn't do it and instead left the phone as-is and gave it to my father who uses it only for calling.

TLDR; There's no official or easy way to get more space. The only two ways that I know of are risky and require at least some technical know-how. You'd be better off getting another phone.